# permission denied executing script over ssh

Tags: ssh, scripting, quoting, remote

When a web page is loaded on server A i want it to run a script on server B. I can do this with a series of commands from server A by logging into server B and executing the script, but it needs to be done all in one statement so that PHP can execute it.

This works:

```
user@A$ sudo -u www-data bash
bash: /home/user/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

Then:

```
www-data@A$ ssh -i /etc/ssh/www-data/id_rsa remote@B
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-generic x86_64)
```

Then:

```
remote@B$ /home/web/script.php
```

(no output, but i can see the results in the database)

So i can see everyone has access to get the message where it's going. But when i try to combine it into one statement:

```
user@A$ sudo -u www-data bash
bash: /home/zen/.bashrc: Permission denied
```

(as apache / php would be)

```
www-data@A$ ssh -i /etc/ssh/www-data/id_rsa remote@B `/home/remote/script.php`
```

then I get:

```
bash: /home/remote/script.php: No such file or directory
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.2.0-32-generic x86_64) ....
```

It also keeps me logged in to B which is irrelevant but strange.

Then just as a sanity test, i continue from there to run the script:

```
remote@B$ /home/remote/script.php
```

Thanks in advance for any advice!!

Answer (score 2):

The order of precedence with the quoting is likely the problem:

```
ssh remote@B `/home/remote/script.php`
```

is very different from:

```
ssh remote@B '/home/remote/script.php'
```

In the first, the shell is calling `script.php` - on the local machine - which likely returns nothing, so the command ends up being `ssh remote@B`, giving you an interactive shell.

The second command passes a statement (`/home/remote/script.php`) through `ssh` to the shell on the remote machine.

Trying changing your back-quotes to single quotes.